# Regex to transform abcd to (a(b(c(d))))

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I'm using PHP's preg_replace, and trying to transform the string

`abcd`

into

`(a(b(c(d))))`

This is the best I've got:

```
preg_replace('/.(?=(.*$))/', '$0($1)', 'abcd');
// a(bcd)b(cd)c(d)d()
```

Is it even possible with regex?

**Edit** I've just discovered this in the PCRE spec: `Replacements are not subject to re-matching`, so my original approach isn't going to work. I wanted to keep it all regex because there's some more complicated matching logic in my actual use case.

Comment: Re: "I wanted to keep it all regex because there's some more complicated matching logic in my actual use case": Can you describe your actual use case, and/or the more complicated matching logic, with sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: You didn't give enough time for others to give this question a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with something along the lines of a combination of the above answers:

```
preg_match_all('/./ui', 'abcd', $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
$string = '('.implode('(', $matches).str_repeat(')', count($matches));
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
preg_replace('/./s', '($0', 'abcd') . str_repeat(')', strlen('abcd'));
```

?

(Does that count as "with regex"?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match_all. Not sure what kind of characters you want, though. So I'll give an example for all characters:

```
$val = 'abcd1234';
$out = '';

if(preg_match_all('#.#', $val, $matches))
{
    $i = 0; // we'll use this to keep track of how many open paranthesis' we have
    foreach($matches[0] as &$v)
    {
        $out .= '('.$v;
        $i++;
    }
    $out .= str_repeat(")", $i);
}
else
{
    // no matches found or error occured
}

echo $out; // (a(b(c(d(1(2(3(4))))))))
```

Will be easy to customise further, as well.

Comment: I'd always use preg_match_all when wanting to do a lot of string processing. Trying to fit a lot of string processing into one preg_replace is like carrying all the shopping from the car in one go. One or two bags at a time is enough.

Comment: It feels more natural in my mind. I mean, without it $v will still remain a reference to the array index, but it's not always the case in PHP, and never the case in C, which I'm also used to. So force of habbit, I guess. Still, I know that if I change it, I'm changing the array, if not, then it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Without &, $v will not be referenced to array value (in what examples will that be true?).

Comment: I didn't say it won't be an array value reference. I said _"without it $v will **still** remain a reference to the array index, but it's not always the case in PHP"_. Not referring to foreach as having any exceptions, but `$array2 = $array` still duplicates the array, and that's why I feel it's more natural to use & whenever I want to specify that the variable is indeed a pointer and not a new value. If PHP was designed again from scratch, I believe this would be standard, because & sometimes being necessary and sometimes not is a bit ambiguous for a programming language.

Comment: Ok, I understand. BUT, if you are doing it this ways, then at least `unset($v);` at the end of the foreach. There will quickly come to error, when you will use variable `$v = '123';` after the foreach, and this will update the last record in the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do it =) :

```
<?php
$arr = str_split("abcd");
$new_arr =  array_reverse($arr);

foreach ($new_arr as $a) {
    $str = sprintf('(%s%s)', $a, $str);
}
echo "$str\n";

?>
```

[KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) isn't it ? (few lines : 6)